# Using std::map with std::pair as a key and list as value

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, std-pair, stdlist

So I have the following map `parseTable`

```
std::map<std::pair<Symbol, Symbol>, list<Symbol> > parseTable;
```

I am confused on how to access to the list value if I have my map initialized this way:

```
std::map<std::pair<Symbol, Symbol>, list<Symbol> > parseTable = { 
        {{Symbol::Input, Symbol::OpenPar}, {Symbol::Expr, Symbol::Semicolon, Symbol::InputP}},
        {{Symbol::Input, Symbol::Ident}, {Symbol::Expr, Symbol::Semicolon, Symbol::InputP}},
        {{Symbol::Input, Symbol::Number}, {Symbol::Expr, Symbol::Semicolon, Symbol::InputP}}
};
```

I want to access to each of the values of my list individually when I use the `find()` function of my map.

This is what I have come up with but I am not able to get a reference to that index value:

```
 if (parseTable.find(std::pair(stack_symbol.top(), current_symbol)))
```

Comment: Why map and not unordered_map?

Comment: If you do not need the values in the list to be ordered, a multimap might be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map::find` will return an iterator to the found element, or to `end` if not found. That iterator will point to a `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, which in your case would translate to

`std::pair< const std::pair<Symbol, Symbol>, list<Symbol> >`

What you want is something like this

```
auto it = parseTable.find(std::pair(stack_symbol.top(), current_symbol));

if (it != parseTable.end()) { // A match was found
    //it->first is std::pair<Symbol, Symbol>
    //it->second is list<Symbol>
    for (auto& symbol : it->second) {
        //symbol is each individual value in the list
        ... do something with symbol
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::pair<const Key, Value>`.

Comment: so `std::pair<const std::pair<Symbol, Symbol>, list<Symbol> >`

Answer (score 2):

This is not the greatest choice for map key, it won't let the map to be used efficiently.

[std::map::find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) return an iterator to the place where it found searched item or `std::map::end()` if not found. So, in your `if` statement, you need to check against that:

```
std::map<std::pair<Symbol, Symbol>, list<Symbol> >::iterator iter =
     parseTable.find(std::pair(stack_symbol.top(), current_symbol)) //or auto with C++11
if (iter != parseTable.end())
```

`find` returns an iterator, to access the object (which will be of type `std::pair<std::pair<Symbol, Symbol>, list<Symbol>>`, you'll need dereference operator `*`

```
Symbol currentSymbol = (*iter).first.second; //dummy example to show the use
std::list<Symbol> myList = (*iter).second'
```